# Referencing features not in brackets in GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, geojson, fields-attributes, maplibre-gl

I'm using this maplibre example to create a hover effect over GeoJSON features: https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js-docs/example/hover-styles/

The GeoJSON looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[coordinates]]
      },
      "properties": {
        "STATE_ID": "54",
        "STATE_NAME": "West Virginia"
      },
      "id": 54
    },
  ]
};
```

and is referenced successfully with:

```
map.on('mousemove', 'state-fills', function (e) {
  if (e.features.length > 0) {
    if (hoveredStateId) {
      map.setFeatureState(
        { source: 'states', id: hoveredStateId },
        { hover: false }
      );
    }
    hoveredStateId = e.features[0].id;//this is the important part
    map.setFeatureState(
      { source: 'states', id: hoveredStateId },
      { hover: true }
    );
  }
});
```

But when I change the GeoJSON to this:

```
{
  'type': 'FeatureCollection',
  'name': 'countygeo',
  'features': [
    { 'type': 'Feature', 
      'properties': { 'id': 2, 'OBJECTID': 1201, 'NAME': 'Traill', 'STATE_NAME': 'North Dakota', 'STATE_FIPS': '38', 'CNTY_FIPS': '097', 'FIPS': '38097', 'POPULATION': 8154, 'POP_SQMI': 9.5, 'POP2010': 8121, 'POP10_SQMI': 9.4, 'WHITE': 7809, 'BLACK': 42, 'AMERI_ES': 64, 'ASIAN': 21, 'HAWN_PI': 1, 'HISPANIC': 214, 'OTHER': 89, 'MULT_RACE': 95, 'MALES': 4067, 'FEMALES': 4054, 'AGE_UNDER5': 510, 'AGE_5_9': 465, 'AGE_10_14': 504, 'AGE_15_19': 604, 'AGE_20_24': 528, 'AGE_25_34': 786, 'AGE_35_44': 910, 'AGE_45_54': 1237, 'AGE_55_64': 1056, 'AGE_65_74': 662, 'AGE_75_84': 539, 'AGE_85_UP': 320, 'MED_AGE': 42.4, 'MED_AGE_M': 40.7, 'MED_AGE_F': 44.1, 'HOUSEHOLDS': 3394, 'AVE_HH_SZ': 2.29, 'HSEHLD_1_M': 515, 'HSEHLD_1_F': 547, 'MARHH_CHD': 726, 'MARHH_NO_C': 1112, 'MHH_CHILD': 62, 'FHH_CHILD': 136, 'FAMILIES': 2150, 'AVE_FAM_SZ': 2.88, 'HSE_UNITS': 3780, 'VACANT': 386, 'OWNER_OCC': 2443, 'RENTER_OCC': 951, 'NO_FARMS12': 468, 'AVE_SIZE12': 1170, 'CROP_ACR12': 526183, 'AVE_SALE12': 659887, 'SQMI': 862.51, 'Shape_Leng': 2.1504488669400001, 'Shape_Area': 0.26636235028499999, 'Shape__Area': 4881825510.71875, 'Shape__Length': 283774.46460703999, 'GlobalID': '6d3199a6-fe70-4984-aceb-a7eceb1879a6' }, 
      'geometry': { 'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [ [ coordinates ] ] } },
]
};
```

I can't figure out how to reference the `'id'`. In the original, `'id'` is under `'features'`, but in the new GeoJSON, `'id'` is under `'properties'`, which is under 'features'.

The only way I can get it to work is to add brackets to the properties like so:

```
{
  'type': 'FeatureCollection',
  'name': 'countygeo',
  'features': [
    { 'type': 'Feature',
      'properties': [{ 'id': 2, 'OBJECTID': 1201, 'NAME': 'Traill', 'STATE_NAME': 'North Dakota', 'STATE_FIPS': '38', 'CNTY_FIPS': '097', 'FIPS': '38097', 'POPULATION': 8154, 'POP_SQMI': 9.5, 'POP2010': 8121, 'POP10_SQMI': 9.4, 'WHITE': 7809, 'BLACK': 42, 'AMERI_ES': 64, 'ASIAN': 21, 'HAWN_PI': 1, 'HISPANIC': 214, 'OTHER': 89, 'MULT_RACE': 95, 'MALES': 4067, 'FEMALES': 4054, 'AGE_UNDER5': 510, 'AGE_5_9': 465, 'AGE_10_14': 504, 'AGE_15_19': 604, 'AGE_20_24': 528, 'AGE_25_34': 786, 'AGE_35_44': 910, 'AGE_45_54': 1237, 'AGE_55_64': 1056, 'AGE_65_74': 662, 'AGE_75_84': 539, 'AGE_85_UP': 320, 'MED_AGE': 42.4, 'MED_AGE_M': 40.7, 'MED_AGE_F': 44.1, 'HOUSEHOLDS': 3394, 'AVE_HH_SZ': 2.29, 'HSEHLD_1_M': 515, 'HSEHLD_1_F': 547, 'MARHH_CHD': 726, 'MARHH_NO_C': 1112, 'MHH_CHILD': 62, 'FHH_CHILD': 136, 'FAMILIES': 2150, 'AVE_FAM_SZ': 2.88, 'HSE_UNITS': 3780, 'VACANT': 386, 'OWNER_OCC': 2443, 'RENTER_OCC': 951, 'NO_FARMS12': 468, 'AVE_SIZE12': 1170, 'CROP_ACR12': 526183, 'AVE_SALE12': 659887, 'SQMI': 862.51, 'Shape_Leng': 2.1504488669400001, 'Shape_Area': 0.26636235028499999, 'Shape__Area': 4881825510.71875, 'Shape__Length': 283774.46460703999, 'GlobalID': '6d3199a6-fe70-4984-aceb-a7eceb1879a6' }], 
  'geometry': { 'type': 'Polygon', 
    'coordinates': [ [ coordinates ] ] } },
]
};
```

and then reference it as so:

```
map.on('mousemove', 'state-fills', function (e) {
    if (e.features.length > 0) {
        if (hoveredStateId) {
            map.setFeatureState(
                { source: 'states', id: hoveredStateId },
                { hover: false }
            );
        }
        hoveredStateId = e.features[0].properties.id;//this is the important part
        map.setFeatureState(
            { source: 'states', id: hoveredStateId },
            { hover: true }
        );
    }
});
```

But, my data doesn't look like that, and I'd rather not edit it all to add the brackets. I want to understand how the referencing structure looks like with `[]` as opposed to `{}`.

[fiddle with sample data in "real" format](http://jsfiddle.net/5k3bzwdt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference the "id" in the properties object, change:

```
hoveredStateId = e.features[0].id;
```

to:

```
hoveredStateId = e.features[0].properties.id;
```

(I see that that is the code you have in your "not working" example, but it shouldn't work with the "modified" GeoJSON  you have posted)

[proof of concept fiddle (uses existing "STATE_ID" in the properties object)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5spra4ex/)

**update:**
There are two options described in the [documentation](https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js-docs/api/map/#map#setfeaturestate) to solve this issue:

> - For vector or GeoJSON sources, using the `promoteId` option at the time the source is defined.
> - For GeoJSON sources, using the `generateId` option to auto-assign an id based on the feature's index in the source data. If you change feature data using map.getSource('some id').setData(..), you may need to re-apply state taking into account updated id values.

Both valid when you create the source:

```
map.on('load', function () {
  map.addSource('states', {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data': states,
    'promoteId': 'id',  // or 'generateId': true
  });
```

[updated fiddle (using your posted data)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/o49Lq7my/)

[image: screenshot of fiddle with highlighting]